# Can't see image in ImageView android

Tags: android, imageview

I am trying to populate ListView Item with an object from MyClass. One of the property of the class is jpg image. I put my images in images/ folder. I use this code for populating

```
private static final String ASSETS_DIR = "images/";
String imgFilePath=ASSETS_DIR+r.resourceID;

    try{
    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imgFilePath);
    resourceIdView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);


    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        System.out.println(" Error");

    }
```

r.resourceID is the name of the image for example "AUD.jpg" 
resourceIDView is ImageView 
The program don't get in the catch part, however I can't see the image
could somebody help me??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your naming convention I conclude that you are storing your images in the "assets" folder. If yes, then you can use the following lines of code and get this issue resolved:

```
private static final String ASSETS_DIR = "images/";
String imgFilePath=ASSETS_DIR+r.resourceID;

try{
    Drawable d = Drawable.createFromStream(getAssets().open(imgFilePath), null);
    resourceIdView.setImageDrawable(d);
}
catch(Exception e)
{
    System.out.println(" Error");

}
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

put your image  in drawable folder and set so imageview...

```
 resourceIdView.setImageResource(R.drawable.AUD);
```

Comment: I have list of images and I have a custom arrayadapter for populating ListView.How can I connect the list with main.xml?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to put your images in drawable folder under /res. Use an `ImageAdapter`that extend `BaseAdapter`to populate your ListView. You can use this code : http://www.java2s.com/Code/Android/2D-Graphics/extendsBaseAdaptertocreateImageadapter.htm

Answer (score 0):

What I had was that the image was showing in Designer but not on device, so I put the image in all the drawable-xdpi directories. This worked for me.